# MaterializeCSS - Elements not appearing inside a Tab

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm having a very annoying problem using Materialize in my website - the height of the entire html tag seems to be fixed for some reason, and this is causing problems, such as essential elements to the page not appearing at the bottom, since they are cut from the content. However, with F12, the element is still there, just out of the viewport of the html.

[image: You can see here the <code><html></code> tag is limiting my content vertically.]

The problem is reproduced here, tested with the latest Google Chrome version:

```css
.input-field label {
  color: #000;
}

/* label focus color */
.input-field input[type=email]:focus+label {
  color: #33691e !important;
}

/* label underline focus color */
.input-field input[type=email]:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #33691e !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #64dd17 !important;
}

/* valid color */
.input-field input[type=email].valid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #64dd17;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;
}

/* invalid color */
.input-field input[type=email].invalid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;
}

/* icon prefix focus color */
.input-field .prefix.active {
  color: #000;
}

.input-field input[type=password]:focus+label {
  color: #33691e !important;
}

/* label underline focus color */
.input-field input[type=password]:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #33691e !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #64dd17 !important;
}

.input-field input[type=text]:focus+label {
  color: #33691e !important;
}

/* label underline focus color */
.input-field input[type=text]:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #33691e !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #64dd17 !important;
}

/* valid color */
.input-field input[type=text].valid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #64dd17;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;
}

/* invalid color */
.input-field input[type=text].invalid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;
}

.tabs .tab a {
  color: #33691e !important;
}

/*Black color to the text*/

.tabs .tab a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f8e9 !important;
  color: #33691e !important;
}

/*Text color on hover*/

.tabs .tab a.active {
  background-color: #dcedc8 !important;
  color: #33691e !important;
}

/*Background and text color when a tab is active*/

.tabs .indicator {
  background-color: #33691e !important;
}

/*Color of underline*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div style='text-align: center; height: 100px;'>
          <img src='/cocamar/imagens/Transcocamar_horizontal.png' style='width: 60%;margin: 0 auto; margin-top:-5%;' alt='This is a header image'>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row' style='margin-top:-20px;'>
        <small style='float: right;'>
          <b>Motorista: Fulano</b><br>
          <b>Placa: AAA-1234</b>
        </small>
        <h4>Cargas</h4>
      </div>
      <div style='margin-top: -20px;'>
        <div class='col s12'>
          <ul class='tabs' id='tabs1'>
            <li class='tab col s4'><a href='#atual' class='active'>Atual</a></li>
            <li class='tab col s4'><a href='#disponiveis'>Disponíveis</a></li>
            <li class='tab col s4'><a href='#historico'>Histórico</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="atual" class="col s12">
          <div class='container'>
            <div class='card'>
              <div class='container'>
                <p><b>Carga</b></p>
                <p><b>Status</b></p>
                <p><b>Peso</b></p>
                <p><b>Valor</b></p>
                <p><b>Entregas</b></p>
                <p><b>Municípios</b></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
              <button type='button' class='col s12 btn waves-effect'>Enviar Local</button>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
              <button type='button' class='col s12 btn waves-effect'>Digitar canhoto</button>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
              <button type='button' class='col s6 btn waves-effect'>Detalhar</button>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
              <button type='button' class='col s6 btn waves-effect'>Ver Mapa</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="disponiveis" class="col s12">
          <h2>Disponiveis</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="historico" class="col s12">
          <h2>Historico</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var tabElems1 = document.querySelector("#tabs1");
      var tabInstances1 = M.Tabs.init(tabElems1, {
        swipeable: true
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

OR
https://jsfiddle.net/ptqgdf8x/

As you can see, the last button ("Ver mapa") doesn't appear in the page, since it's out of the viewport.

I've already tried removing all of my own CSS which could be interfering with Materialize, but the problem persisted. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tabs have a direct style applied:

```
<div class="tabs-content carousel carousel-slider" style="height: 400px;">
```

I've had a similar issue to this in the past relating to carousels, changing your initialisation of your carousel with a larger height should fix the issue.

Are you using Jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
         height: 500
    });
});
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed this. I'm not using Jquery with Materialize seeing as it's not required anymore, but I've managed to fix this by declaring an !important min-height to the .carousel class. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DootyBooty Good to know you've come to a solution!